# Manually Raise TimeoutException for testing

Tags: c#, web-services, http, web, request

I have return some code that calls external API. What happens sometimes is that my http request times out (not always). I modified my code and handled the `TimeOutException` in my code. Now I want to test this code.

How can test this timeout exception by generating it manually using some http request which surely get time out?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I've used two ways in the past:

**Fiddler**

If the external API is REST-based, then either:

- Use the "Simulate Modem Speeds" rule. Go to the `Rules -> Performance -> Simulate Modem Speeds` menu option.
- *Or* use the AutoResponder feature to return the 408 status code when the API is hit. See [Fiddler Autoresponder docs](http://docs.telerik.com/fiddler/knowledgebase/autoresponder) for more details (it's easier than it looks).

**SoapUI Mock Service**

If the external API is Soap-based, SoapUI is clunky at times but it is great for this type of testing. You can create a mock service based on some WSDL and control exactly how it responds, e.g. return a HTTP 408 status code